# Changing the mac desktop icon resize shortcut in finder

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, icons, zoom, size

By default finder has a keyboard shortcut for changing icon size/zoom, `⌘ =` and `⌘ -`.
If you are like me you press these on accident and the result is desktop icons all over the place as the grid overflows. How do you disable this shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret for solving this problem is knowing the menu names for the commands, and as it so happens these two commands are not listed in any of the finder windows. I was able to figure them out by turning on voice over accessibility tools and then executing the commands. This revealed them to be `Increase Icon Size` and `Decrease Icon Size`

Knowing this we can go into system preferences > keyboard > shortcuts. Click on App Shortcuts on the left, then click the plus button to add the following, highlighted in magenta.[image]

It should be noted that by default, `⌘ =` AND `⇧ ⌘ =` both control this same `Increase Icon Size` command, and likewise `⌘ -` and `⇧ ⌘ -` both control this same `Decrease Icon Size`. Setting these commands to their alternate default keeps the shift method intact if you desire it while disabling the more common zoom shortcuts.

Comment: I like the trick of using Accessibility to find the command name. Would never have occurred to me.

Comment: I'm tempted to say - post that trick as a QA all of its own, on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ I'm sure it would be a useful addition.